# Avoid fixed filter date in SQL grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

Consider the code:

```
Declare @A table (
    SoldDate Date,
    ItemName varchar(100),
    Cost float
)

Insert into @A VALUES 
('2022-01-19','Item A',0.156),
('2022-05-02','Item B',1.4752),
('2022-09-13','Item C',0.782155),
('2022-12-07','Item D',2.4260),
('2023-01-11','Item A',0.1),
('2023-04-14','Item B',-0.1546),
('2023-05-22','Item C',19.152),
('2023-06-18','Item D',0.000175),
('2023-07-03','Item A',1),
('2023-09-29','Item B',23.41),
('2023-10-19','Item C',7.24),
('2023-11-10','Item D',13.4)

Select
ItemName, Sum(Cost) As [Sum Of Cost], iif(SoldDate >= '01-Nov-2022','2023','2022') as Year
From @A

Group By
ItemName, iif(SoldDate >= '01-Nov-2022','2023','2022')
```

The fixed date is the issue; I want to change it to a dynamic calc (latest SoldDate minus one year),but the SQL is being used in an external app which doesn't allow for temp variables.

I have tried the dynamic query:

```
Select
ItemName, Sum(Cost) As [Sum Of Cost], iif(SoldDate >= dateadd(year,-1,max(SoldDate)),'2023','2022') as Year
From @A

Group By
ItemName, iif(SoldDate >= dateadd(year,-1,max(SoldDate)),'2023','2022')
```

But I get the error

> Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause".

Is there any do this as part of one query?

Comment: you can calculate max(solddate) over() in a subquery and then use it for you formula

Comment: Thanks - I don't understand what you mean, please can you help?

Comment: Something like: `Select
ItemName, Sum(Cost) As [Sum Of Cost]
, iif(SoldDate >= dateadd(year,-1,maxDt),'2023','2022') AS Year
From (
 select *
 , max(soldDate) OVER() AS maxDt
 FROM @A
 ) x
Group By ItemName, iif(SoldDate >= dateadd(year,-1,maxDt),'2023','2022')`

Comment: Side note, you should not be using `float` for money, you will run into rounding issues. float is intended for scientific data only.

Comment: Another side note: If you are working with fiscal years (FYs) ranging from November through October, a more generalized calculation than your `IIF()` would be `SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(month, 2, SoldDate)) AS FY FROM ...`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use MAX(soldDate) - one year as your new threshold? If you had a query that behaved as expected for all of 2023, but stopped giving expected results in 2024, you more likely need to just generalize the FY calculation using the  `YEAR(DATEADD(month, 2, SoldDate))`. If not, do really want to count 2024 sales as "2023" or should the calculated "Year" value match the end of the selected year-long period. What about sales more than two years old? Should they still be grouped with prior-year sales?

Comment: I'm using rolling 12 months - with the data being updated monthly. So while the max date is within Nov 2023 then we set the prior year as ending 01/11/2022. When the December data is loading the prior year ends 01/12/2022. I like the cross apply method but using it as you stated has resulted in ~10,000 more rows in the data too!

Comment: I am using @Siggemannen' s code - it works fine but obviously adds slightly more time due to the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a query that behaved as expected for most of 2023, but recently stopped giving desired results, I don't think this is a case where you need to redefine your *year-window*. You more likely need to just generalize the FY calculation with something like `YEAR(DATEADD(month, 2, SoldDate))`.

This calculation can be wrapped up in a `CROSS APPLY` to avoid having to define it twice.

```
Select
    ItemName,
    Sum(Cost) As [Sum Of Cost],
    FY.Year
From @A
Cross Apply (Select year(dateadd(month, 2, SoldDate)) As Year) FY
Group By
    ItemName,
    FY.Year
```

Results:

| ItemName | Sum Of Cost | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item A | 0.156 | 2022 |
| Item B | 1.4752 | 2022 |
| Item C | 0.782155 | 2022 |
| Item A | 1.1 | 2023 |
| Item B | 23.2554 | 2023 |
| Item C | 26.392 | 2023 |
| Item D | 2.426175 | 2023 |
| Item D | 13.4 | 2024 |

Note that the sales now span three fiscal years:

- FY 2022 - November 2021 through October 2022
- FY 2023 - November 2022 through October 2023
- FY 2024 - November 2023 through October 2024

If you *really* need to use a sliding year definition based on `max(SoldDate)`, you can calculate `max(SoldDate)` once in a CTE or subselect. (If the `SoldDate` column is indexed, this will be a fast and simple index seek.) You can then use it to calculate the "sales year" or whatever you might call it by combining teh calendar-year with a conditional +1 adjustment based on a comparison of just the MM/DD portions of the dates..

```
Select
    A.ItemName,
    Sum(A.Cost) As [Sum Of Cost],
    SY.Year
From @A A
Cross Apply (
    Select year(A.SoldDate)
        + IIF(CONVERT(CHAR(5), A.SoldDate) > CONVERT(CHAR(5), M.MaxSoldDate), 1, 0)
        As Year
    From (Select max(soldDate) As MaxSoldDate From @A) M
) SY
Group By
    A.ItemName, SY.Year
```

I changed

Results:

| ItemName | Sum Of Cost | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item A | 0.156 | 2022 |
| Item B | 1.4752 | 2022 |
| Item C | 0.782155 | 2022 |
| Item D | 2.426 | 2022 |
| Item A | 1.1 | 2023 |
| Item B | 23.2554 | 2023 |
| Item C | 26.392 | 2023 |
| Item D | 13.400175 | 2023 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LxiHThhM)